# I am creating client application in java using tinkerpop for gremlin but i am unable to query through my application. JanusGraph and Gremlin server

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am trying to build client application in java for gremlin. My janusgraph server is running on one more virtual machine in the same network. Through my gremlin client code i am able to establish connection between client and server but i am unable to query to server from my client application i am facing serialization and index array out of bond exception. Below is my code

`````
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.build()
                .addContactPoint("192.168.21.121")
                .port(8182)
                .enableSsl(false)
                .minConnectionPoolSize(1)
                .maxConnectionPoolSize(10)
                .maxWaitForConnection(200000)
                 .serializer(Serializers.GRYO_V3D0)  // Adjust this based on your JanusGraph server setup
                .create();
                GraphTraversalSource g = traversal()
                .withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster)
                        // Adjust based on server compatibility
                );
                try {
                    // Add two vertices
                    Vertex vertex1 = g.addV("person").property("name", "John Doe").property("age", 30).next();
                    Vertex vertex2 = g.addV("person").property("name", "Jane Doe").property("age", 28).next();
        
                    System.out.println("Vertices added with IDs: " + vertex1.id() + ", " + vertex2.id());
        
                    // Add an edge between the two vertices
                    Edge addedEdge = g.V(vertex1).addE("knows").to(vertex2).property("relationshipType", "friend").next();
        
                    System.out.println("Edge added with ID: " + addedEdge.id());
                } finally {
                    cluster.close();
                }
            }
}

*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
Error:-
prajwal@prajwal-patil:~/Desktop/test_netconf/graph$  cd /home/prajwal/Desktop/test_netconf/graph ; /usr/bin/env /usr/jdk1.8.0_202/bin/java -cp /tmp/cp_1zht1jxqth1ppqvnhvvmhm5an.jar com.janus.graph.App 
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/prajwal/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.30/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/prajwal/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
0    [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Connection  - Created new connection for ws://192.168.21.121:8182/gremlin
1    [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ConnectionPool  - Opening connection pool on Host{address=192.168.21.121/192.168.21.121:8182, hostUri=ws://192.168.21.121:8182/gremlin} with core size of 1
86   [gremlin-driver-loop-1] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.MessageSerializer  - Response [SimpleLeakAwareByteBuf(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 57, widx: 57, cap: 57))] could not be deserialized by org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.AbstractGryoMessageSerializerV3d0.
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 127, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.util.MapReferenceResolver.getReadObject(MapReferenceResolver.java:60)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.readReferenceOrNull(Kryo.java:834)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:684)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.AbstractGryoMessageSerializerV3d0.deserializeResponse(AbstractGryoMessageSerializerV3d0.java:155)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.handler.WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.decode(WebSocketGremlinResponseDecoder.java:50)
        at org.apache.tink````

I am trying to add vertex from my client application and the same need to be stored in cassendra backend.
`````

Comment: What does your Gremlin Server configuration look like, specifically which serializers are configured server side?

Comment: i am configuring GRYO_V1D0 this is my serialization in client side

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you are using Gryo 1 in one of your comments associated with your question, but your client code in the questions says Gryo 3. I'm not clear if that's a mistake or not, but the server and the client both need the same serializer configured or else they won't communicate properly.

You also don't mention what version of TinkerPop you are using, but note that [Gryo was removed](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.6.0/upgrade/#_removed_gryo_messageserializers) as a supported serialization format in 3.6.0. It would be best if you chose GraphBinary instead.

Comment: Thank you I have resolved the issue. The issue was serialization I had used .serializer(Serializers. GRAPHSON) now I can communicate properly with my client and server.